# How to disable Quicktype for UITextField

Tags: keyboard, uitextfield, ios9

I have a login screen in my application and it has `UITextField` for user's email. I want to disable Quicktype view on the system keyboard only for this field. I tried all approaches posted on SO but still didn't find a solution. Under Quictype view I mean this:

[image]

I have this in Interface Builder for my text field

[image]

Also I tried this and it does not work:

```
myTextFIELD.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

I use iOS 8/9 and Xcode 7.x

If anybody has a solution how to make it done share it please.